# DirectShow DMO Color Converter

Tags: directshow, directshow.net, graphedit

I am having an issue with connecting the Color Converter DMO object in graphedit (graphstudio, and in code). It works on one machine and turns green in graphedit, however on the machine I have to demo the program on it will not connect! I've looked at sdks, installs, and the machine should mimic my machine.

I also noticed that I can reregister the filter on my machine with regsvr however it fails on the other machine.

Any ideas as to what the culprit could be?

Answer (score 0):

1. Why would you want to re-register it, it is either a core OS component, or not available at all
2. It is not a filter, it is dual interface DMO/DSP and while it is available within DirectShow through `DMO Wrapper Filter`, this use scenario is not guaranteed to work out smoothly and you possibly have to workaround issues.

Having wrapped it through DirectShow.NET library, the number of issues might increase, so you have to gather and provide more details about the errors on the way (HRESULTs etc).